# Carbon/PHP causing diffInMonths to return the wrong value when February is involved

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon, time-difference

I am trying to determine the difference in months between the date the user is created and the current date.

However, if any of the date involves february it will result in the difference being returned to potentially be wrong.

Instead of returning difference of 1 it is returning 0.

**Code**

```
   $associated_user_created_at = Carbon::parse("2023-02-01 00:00:00");
    $currentDate = Carbon::parse("2023-03-01 23:59:59");
    error_log("H E L L O ");
    error_log($associated_user_created_at->format('d F Y'));
    error_log($currentDate->format('d F Y'));
    $diffInMonths = $associated_user_created_at->diffInMonths($currentDate, false);
    // $diffInMonths = $associated_user_created_at->diff($currentDate);
    error_log("****");
    error_log("Diff in months = " .$diffInMonths);
    dd($diffInMonths);
```

**Output**

```
H E L L O
01 February 2023
01 March 2023
****
Diff in months = 0
```

I have tried following the suggested solutions in this thread [Incorrect diffInMonths laravel Carbon between Feb 1 and Mar 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124152/incorrect-diffinmonths-laravel-carbon-between-feb-1-and-mar-1/76617958#76617958) however it doesn't solve the issue.

**Project specifications**

- Php 7.4.25
- Laravel 5

Comment: Keep in mind that Laravel 5 is horribly outdated! Are you sure this is related to Laravel after all? What do all these `error_log` lines print?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have edited the post to include the output

Comment: Tough subject, as there is many ways to calculate month diff, each being correct or not depending on the use case https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/2604

Comment: And then what is your version of Carbon? It's probably outdated. IIRC Laravel 5 is stuck with Carbon v1

Comment: This is likely a carbon or php version bug because on PHP 8.2 and  Laravel 10  (using Carbon 2+) this works as expected. If this is the only wrong case you can probably hardcode the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you should not use Carbon::diffInMonths() for that because your version is outdated. Then for anniversary-style month diff, you can:

```
$year = $associated_user_created_at->year;
$month = $associated_user_created_at->month;
$day = $associated_user_created_at->day;
$diff = ($currentDate->year - $year) * 12 + $currentDate->month - $month - ($currentDate->day < $day ? 1 : 0);
```

(Assuming currentDate >= associated_user_created_at)

Comment: Thanks! It actually is returning the expected output, but can you elaborate on why diffInMonths isn't working for me?

And what do you mean by anniversary style month diff

Comment: When using your code with the last version of Carbon, the diff is `1` and diffInMonth() get reworked many times so I assume you get `0` because you use an old version.

Anniversary-style is the calculation of the diff from start then counting +1 every time you reach the same day number on next month (of full month if they don't contain this day number)

See https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/2604

Answer (score -1):

You can use this solution to get the number of different month using Carbon diffnInMonth

```
$associated_user_created_at = Carbon::parse("2023-02-01 00:00:00")->format('Y-m-d');
$currentDate = Carbon::parse("2023-03-01 23:59:59")->format('Y-m-d');
$monthDiff = Carbon::parse($currentDate)->diffInMonths(Carbon::parse($associated_user_created_at));
dd($monthDiff);
```

Comment: What is "this? Please add some explanation to your answer, such that others can learn from it. Shouldn't `$currentDate` contain a string after using `format`?

Comment: @NicoHaase Edit the answer with a proper explanation.

Comment: What does `dd($currentDate)` yield?

Comment: @NicoHaase to print the $monthDiff.

Comment: What do you mean by "to print"? Please check what`$currentDate` contains. Calling `format()` returns a string, and you cannot use `diffInMonths` on a string

Comment: @NicoHaase Updated the answer please check it.

Comment: "carbon DiffnInMonth is only applicable on date not timestamp" - do you have any credible source for this claim?

Comment: @NicoHaase- Updated the answer explanation.